# how to split or get contents of div with inner div separate on new line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```js
<div id="nlp_selected_day">
  <div class="nlp_months nlp_selected_month_calendar_shown" style="display: inline-block;"><div class="nlp_day_selected_dummy_day"></div>
  <div class="nlp_day_selected_dummy_day"></div>
  <div class="nlp_day_selected_dummy_day"></div>
  <div id="1" class="nlp_day_selected nlp_thursday" value="1" title="Четвъртък"> 1
  <div></div></div>
    <div id="2" class="nlp_day_selected nlp_friday" value="2" title="Петък"> 2
    <div class="calendar_day_container"></div></div>
      
    ......
    <div id="5" class="nlp_day_selected nlp_monday" value="5" title="Понеделник"> 5
    <div class="calendar_day_container">
      <div>8:00 - 8:45 </div>
      <div class="hidden_info">
        <div class="hidden_title">Запазено!</div>
        <div class="hidden_description"><br></div>
        </div>
      <div>8:45 - 9:30 </div>
        <div class="hidden_info">
          <div class="hidden_title">Запазено!</div>
          <div class="hidden_description"><br></div>
          </div>
      <div>9:40 - 10:25 </div>
         <div class="hidden_info">
           <div class="hidden_title">Запазено!</div>
           <div class="hidden_description"><br></div>
           </div>
      <div>10:25 - 11:10 </div>
         <div class="hidden_info">
           <div class="hidden_title">Запазено!</div>
           <div class="hidden_description"><br></div>
           </div>
      <div>11:20 - 12:05 </div>
        ....... 
    <div id="6" class="nlp_day_selected nlp_tuesday" value="6" title="Вторник"> 6
    <div class="calendar_day_container">
      <div>8:00 - 8:45 </div>
        <div class="hidden_info">
          <div class="hidden_title">Запазено!</div>
          <div class="hidden_description"><br></div>
        </div>
      <div>8:45 - 9:30 </div>
        <div class="hidden_info">
          <div class="hidden_title">Запазено!</div>
          <div class="hidden_description"><br></div>
      ......
```

I get content with this code:

```js
jQuery('.nlp_day_selected').click(function (){
        var contents = $(this).children('.calendar_day_container').text();
        $('#nlp_show_content').html(contents);
    });
```

but I want to get content divided into a new line each time block

something like this:

> 14:40 - 15:25 100 минути descriptions
>
> 15:25 - 16:10 title descriptions
>
> 16:20 - 17:05 title descriptions

Comment: Where is your  '#nlp_show_content' class?

Comment: @eugensunic #nlp_show_content is an id selector

Comment: I don't think your jQuery code snippet is the best way to get at the data you want but regardless, what is the sample output of that code snippet? Could you include that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I believe your question could have been phrased better, I will still make an attempt to answer your question.

First of all, it could be your formatting, but I think you have some `</div>` tags that have no opening `<div>` tags, you should check to see if that is an actual error or not (you might have copy pasted wrong who knows).

Furthermore, I think you should make a few small changes to your code to make it a bit easier to get at the data you want.

You should change all code that looks like this:

```
<div>10:25 - 11:10 </div>
   <div class="hidden_info">
   <div class="hidden_title">Запазено!</div>
   <div class="hidden_description"><br></div>
```

To something like this:

```
<div class="timeslot_container">   
   <div class="timeslot">10:25 - 11:10 </div>
   <div class="hidden_info">
   <div class="hidden_title">Запазено!</div>
   <div class="hidden_description"><br></div>
</div>
```

And then, you can do something like this using jQuery (modify it to fit your needs):

```
var contents = $("<div></div>");
$('.calendar_day_container').each(function (i, elt) {
    var $htmlForOneDay = $("<div></div>");
    $(elt).find(".timeslot_container").each(function (i, elt) {
        var $singleTimeslot = $("<div></div>");
        $singleTimeslot.append($(elt).find(".timeslot").text()).append(" ");
        $singleTimeslot.append($(elt).find(".hidden_title").text()).append(" ");
        $singleTimeslot.append($(elt).find(".hidden_description").text());
        $htmlForOneDay.append($singleTimeslot).append($("<br/>"));
    });
    contents.append($htmlForOneDay).append("<hr/>"); // you can skip the <hr/> if you want
});
$('#nlp_show_content').html(contents[0]);
```

I believe this will get you the data in the format you want, or at least lead you in the right direction, I hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Loop over all of the `hidden_info` class and use those instances to create each line:

```
jQuery('.nlp_day_selected').click(function () {
    var htmlString = '';
    var $hidden = $(this).find('.hidden_info');
    $hidden.each(function () {
        var $el = $(this),
            time = $el.prev().text(),// time is in previous element
            title = $el.find('.hidden_title').text(),// title is a child
            description = $el.find('.hidden_description').text();// description is a child

        htmlString += time + ' ' + title + ' ' + description + '<br>';
    });    

    $('#nlp_show_content').html(htmlString);
});
```

Not you have full control over each line spacing and formatting

Comment: Thank you so much it really help yes :)